# Zillow API having issues with running basic commands

Tags: python, macos, api, zillow

I am trying to use the Zillow API but I keep getting the following error and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I posted a screenshot of what my API settings are on Zillow and I think that might be the issue but I am not sure. Asking to get my code checked and if my settings are wrong, I've tried changing it but Zillow keeps telling that the website is experiencing an error when I try to change it so I do not know for sure

```
import zillow
key = 'my-zillow-key'
address = "3400 Pacific Ave., Marina Del Rey, CA"
postal_code = "90292"
api = zillow.ValuationApi()
data = api.GetSearchResults(key, address, postal_code)
data = api.GetDeepSearchResults(key, "826 Entrada St, Bossier City, LA", "71111")
```

[image]

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zillow/api
.py", line 130, in GetDeepSearchResults
    place.set_data(xmltodict_data.get('SearchResults:sear
chresults', None)['response']['results']['result'])
KeyError: 'response'

During handling of the above exception, another exception
 occurred:
```

NOTE: neither `data = api.GetSearchResults(key, address, postal_code)
data = api.GetDeepSearchResults(key, "826 Entrada St, Bossier City, LA", "71111")` ran by itself works

Comment: Looks like a bug in the library to me

Comment: like a bug in the Zillow API library?

Comment: Yep. Doesn't appear that it's still maintained. Last update was years ago, and external APIs often change more frequently than that.

Comment: dang that's a bummer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another library called pyzillow. And the APIs work for me. Maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: Please provide a link and maybe some code example :)

Comment: Recommending a third-party library is fine, but you really need to provide more detail about how using that library will solve this problem. For example, as @Yonlif requests, you might provide a short code example showing what the syntax of pyzillow looks like performing similar operations as the OP has outlined. Can you **edit** your answer to provide more information?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I'm using pyzillow.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Zillow API is being (very unceremoniously) turned down. It's possible your original issue was different and would have been addressed by swapping to [pyzillow](https://github.com/hanneshapke/pyzillow), but I suspect at this point you're out of luck unless you can get access to the [Bridge APIs](https://www.bridgeinteractive.com/developers/zillow-group-data/) that Zillow appears to be migrating to.